# How to add the parent class in the div in the Woocommerce?

Tags: html, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am learning the woocommerce. I have to edit the `content-product.php` file. I mean I have to add parents div So I open the page and added the parent class to this `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`.

```
// Ensure visibility.
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}
?>
<li <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?>>
    <div class="products-inner">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>
<div class="product-inner-wrap">
    <div class="">
<div class="product-inner-list">
    
<?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

Now My issue is, Every time I am getting the empty anchor tag.

```
<a href="Product URL" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"></a>
```

My view source is,

```
<div class="product-inner-wrap">
  <a href="Product URL" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
  </a>
  <div class="">
    <a href="Product URL" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
    </a>
    <div class="product-inner-list">
      <a href="Product URL" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
      </a>

      //add to cart button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am expecting the output

```
<div class="product-inner-wrap">
   <div class="">
    <div class="product-inner-list">
      //add to cart button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

suggest by @m4n0 . Is this correct way?

[image]

```
// define the woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item callback 
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item(  ) { 
   echo' <div class="product-inner-wrap">
           <div class="">
            <div class="product-inner-list">
              //add to cart button
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>';

}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: You need to add the HTML to the hook: http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item/ through functions.php Direct editing is not advisable. Replace the `// make action magic happen here... ` with PHP equivalent of outputting it.

Comment: @m4n0, Yes, can you help me with example?

Comment: @m4n0, I updated the code in the question. Can you check it once?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra HTML code in the `content-product.php` template **you have to use hooks where you want the code to be added** *(as rightly suggested by @m4n0)*.

If your goal is to add HTML tags *as shown in the first piece of code* you can use the following hooks:

> Use the HTML **`<span>`** tag instead of the `<div>` if you want to avoid
> creating additional anchor tags.

If you want the link to be shown, replace `span` with `div` in the position you want.
*In this case, for the element with the `product-inner-list` class attribute I replaced `span` with `div`*.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_callback' ); 
function woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_callback() {
    ?>
    <span class="products-inner">
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_callback' ); 
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_callback() {
    ?>
    <span class="product-inner-wrap"><span class=""><div class="product-inner-list">
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_callback' ); 
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_callback() {
    ?>
    </div></span></span></span>
    <?php
}
```

*The code needs to be added to your active theme's functions.php file.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added your code in the function.php but it's still showing the extra anchor tag. Please check the screenshot here https://i.ibb.co/VjPj8MG/Screen-Shot-2021-02-19-at-10-18-13-AM.png

Comment: @user9437856 I have updated my answer *(see last sentence)*.

Comment: If I add hook which is in the reference link and it's removing the anchor tag but it also removing all the product links.

Comment: @user9437856 In the code under *"I am expecting the output"* there is no HTML `a` tag. What do you expect? Do you want to change the link of each product? Could you edit your question in a clearer and more detailed way? Thank you.

Comment: I apologize for not clear. I don't want to change any code. I all the scenarios will be the same. I just want to add the parent div. If I add directly parent div in content-product.php then I am getting the extra anchor tag.(Share source code in the question)

Comment: Yes, Now I am getting the correct structure but Now the issue is, I am not getting the add to cart code inside span. It is displaying outside now. Screenshot here https://i.ibb.co/TgS2dYp/Screen-Shot-2021-02-21-at-3-49-05-PM.png and this is the screenshot when I add directly tags in the content file https://i.ibb.co/j3n22Ny/Screen-Shot-2021-02-21-at-3-54-31-PM.png

Comment: @user9437856 I have updated the answer. Feel free to edit the `span` and `div` tags to make the link show. **Basically the link is added just after opening the `div` tag**.